# Download magnet or .torrent file directly in a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bittorrent

I am trying to create an html hyperlink to download .torrent or magnet file directly from extratorrent.cc like yts.ag is doing but my link is not working?

```html
<a rel="nofollow" title="Download verified torrent file" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:d84ac81cb6bb3ae055aca1a75b4ddeb30f00e38b&dn=Suicide.Squad.2016.EXTENDED.720p.WEBRip.x264.AAC-ETRG&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce">Download torrent</a>
```

Comment: Your code is correct. It should work on any PC or Mobile having a torrent download client.

Comment: Regretfully, it is not working so on i have posted the thread here so that some experts could help me make it work.

Comment: Its working. I'm downloading Suicide Squad by clicking your link. The problem must be in your download client.

Comment: Where did you check it, Can you email me the demo page to my email istuff360@gmail.com

Comment: When i click on it it is showing an error that torcache is not working, is there any alternate to do it?

Comment: It's working now 100% both .torrent file and also magnet, yoho!

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working with the given link? And how is this related to Javascript, jQuery, and PHP, while you haven't shared a single line of code in these languages?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a rel="nofollow" title="Download verified torrent file" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:d84ac81cb6bb3ae055aca1a75b4ddeb30f00e38b&dn=Suicide.Squad.2016.EXTENDED.720p.WEBRip.x264.AAC-ETRG&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce">Download torrent</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What about using some tool like https://webtorrent.io/intro

```
var WebTorrent = require('webtorrent')

var client = new WebTorrent()

var magnetURI = 'magnet: ...'

client.add(magnetURI, { path: '/path/to/folder' }, function (torrent) {   torrent.on('done', function () {
    console.log('torrent download finished')   }) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a rel="nofollow" title="Download verified torrent file" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:77ABFA4F503AFF7B43FD794270982897B7BBCA1D&dn=Adipurush+2023+Hindi+720p+HDTS+x264+AAC+800MB+-+QRips&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.me%3A2970%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.tiny-vps.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopentor.org%3A2710%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.torrent.eu.org%3A451%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.moeking.me%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.cyberia.is%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.me%3A2980%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.to%3A2940%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.uw0.xyz%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopentracker.i2p.rocks%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce">Download torrent</a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).